# Confusion involving Dynamic_Sidebar() in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, sidebar

thanks for reading.

I understand that dynamic_sidebar() accepts a string parameter what correlates with the sidebar name, for instance here:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'bottombar' ); ?>
```

I'm needing to edit the 'bottombar' code but have no idea where to find it. I can't find documentation that highlights this. Is this within my theme files? Is this in the admin? Where do I find the html to edit sidebar 'bottombar'?

Any idea off the top of your head where this points to?

Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your theme's functions.php file, you've registered a sidebar named `'bottombar'`. Hence you are able to call `dynamic_sidebar('bottombar');` with `'bottombar'`.

Details: [Here, read 'Multiple Sidebars' part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)

Comment: Thank you, I found it. I'd searched for a few hours for this answer.